# How to change slider range style?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

I have an input to make a price slider range.
I just want to change its style but nothing works.
What am I missing?

Thanks for any help!

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <input
      id="range"
      type="text"
      data-slider-ticks="[0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]"
      data-slider-ticks-snap-bounds="30"
      data-slider-ticks-labels='["0€", "100€", "200€", "300€", "400€", "500€"]'
    />
  </div>
</div>
{literal}
<style>
  #range {
    height: 5px;
    color: grey;
  }
</style>

<script>
  $("#range").slider({
    ticks: [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
    ticks_labels: ["0€", "100€", "200€", "300€", "400€", "500€"],
    ticks_snap_bounds: 30
  });
</script>
{/literal}
```

The range is ok but the style doesn't apply :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set `type="range"`.

on how to style a range slider checkout  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp

in summary you need to set `-webkit-appearance: none;` then set a background attribute so your height property and other styles can apply.

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <input
      id="range"
      type="range"
      data-slider-ticks="[0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]"
      data-slider-ticks-snap-bounds="30"
      data-slider-ticks-labels='["0€", "100€", "200€", "300€", "400€", "500€"]'
    />
  </div>
</div>
{literal}

<style>
  /* Styling the slider background */
  #range {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 25px;
      background: grey;
      outline: none;
  }
  
  /* Styling the thumb */
  #range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      background: red;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>

{/literal}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me, I changed type = "text" for type = "range" as you suggest but it doesn't change anything, the style doesn't apply. Oh ! I hadn't seen the text below the link sorry, i'm trying

Comment: added your own slider in the snippest.